# Javascript function parameter undefined in IE

Tags: javascript

When I pass a value to my function in internet explorer 8 it keeps returning as undefined. Is there anything that would be causing this behavior I should be looking for? Thanks!

```
$(document).ready(function () {


    myFunction(true);

})


function myFunction(myValue){
    alert(myValue);
//IE8 displays undefined
//Other browsers display true
}
```

EDIT: I added a parameter to the function later on so the page I was calling seemed to be cached by IE, which called the function without setting the parameter.

I guess another question would be why is IE caching the page? I am using the jquery UI dialog to load the page that is calling the function. The script containing the function being called is loaded when the parent page is loaded.

Comment: Not in the code you are showing us.

Comment: @Josiah Your right this code does work. I added a parameter to the function later on so the page I was calling seemed to be cached by IE, which called the function without setting the parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming the alert is just for testing purposes, but everything looks ok. I would try:

alert(myValue?"true":"false");

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I guess it was something else, I have edited my question...And yes the function doesn't actually use the alert I just put that in there to test with.

Answer (score 1):

I've just checked your code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mSgJu/) - it works ok in all browsers!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Your right it does work. I guess it was something else, I have edited my question.